# How to edit a wordpress theme without having to zip and upload?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a new WordPress theme. My issue is wanting to  update the way it looks and see results in real time.

I suppose one option would be to write a script that automates zipping and copies the files over to the themes folder of my locally run WordPress site.

Is this the best way? It doesn't feel very elegant. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have FTP access to the server?

Comment: My concern is that I want to edit and work on it locally, and see local changes in real time.

Comment: Then I don't understand. Why can't you modify files in the theme directory and refresh the browser?

Comment: If your WordPress is local why not edit the files locally? It feels like you do not understand how themes work if you upload them as zip files.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a tool like [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/)  / [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (or whatever you are using currently) and set up a local test install, in this folder you will have `wp-content/themes/your-theme`. You can directly edit files here and keep refreshing your browser to preview changes. Once you are satisfied you can commit to your version control or zip and upload like you do now.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah .. one of the reasons why WP is so popular :)

Comment: Where are my plugin files saved? I am using MAMP on a mac!

Comment: Try `wp-content/plugins`, again you can play around with files here like you did with themes